# How to get parameters after hash mark # from a redirect URL in FastAPI?

Tags: python, http, azure-active-directory, fastapi, url-fragment

I am facing an issue while working with Redirect Url and getting the data from QueryParams in Python using FastApi. I am using Azure AD Authorization Grant Flow to log in, below is the code which generates the `RedirectResponse`

```
@app.get("/auth/oauth/{provider_id}")
async def oauth_login(provider_id: str, request: Request):
    if config.code.oauth_callback is None:
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST,
            detail="No oauth_callback defined",
        )

    provider = get_oauth_provider(provider_id)
    if not provider:
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND,
            detail=f"Provider {provider_id} not found",
        )

    random = random_secret(32)

    params = urllib.parse.urlencode(
        {
            "client_id": provider.client_id,
            "redirect_uri": f"{get_user_facing_url(request.url)}/callback",
            "state": random,
            **provider.authorize_params,
        }
    )
    response = RedirectResponse(
        url=f"{provider.authorize_url}?{params}")
    samesite = os.environ.get("CHAINLIT_COOKIE_SAMESITE", "lax")  # type: Any
    secure = samesite.lower() == "none"
    response.set_cookie(
        "oauth_state",
        random,
        httponly=True,
        samesite=samesite,
        secure=secure,
        max_age=3 * 60,
    )
    return response
```

And this is where I am receiving the Redirect URL.

```
@app.get("/auth/oauth/{provider_id}/callback")
async def oauth_callback(
    provider_id: str,
    request: Request,
    error: Optional[str] = None,
    code: Optional[str] = None,
    state: Optional[str] = None,
):
    if config.code.oauth_callback is None:
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST,
            detail="No oauth_callback defined",
        )
    provider = get_oauth_provider(provider_id)
    if not provider:
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND,
            detail=f"Provider {provider_id} not found",
        )


    
    if not code or not state:
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST,
            detail="Missing code or state",
        )
    response.delete_cookie("oauth_state")
    return response
```

This redirect works fine when the QueryParams are with ? but the issue right now is that the redirect callback from Azure AD is with # and due to that I am not able to get the `Code` & `State` QueryParams from the Url

##### Example of RedirectUrl with `#`

`http://localhost/callback#code=xxxxxx&state=yyyyyy`

Any thoughts on how to fix this issue.

Comment: Looks like you have been using the wrong OAuth flow.

Comment: How come? Using authorize endpoint first to get code & id_token using Hybrid Flow for Azure AD. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow#request-an-id-token-as-well-or-hybrid-flow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting get the text (or key-value pairs, in your case) after the hash mark `#` on server side— the `#` in a URL is also known as the [URI fragment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_fragment) (see [Text fragments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Text_fragments) on MDN documentation as well)—is currently **not possible**. This is simply because the fragment is **never** sent to the server (related posts can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8033537) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2317508)).

I would suggest using the [question mark in the URL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72068032/17865804) `?`, which is the proper way to send query parameters in an HTTP request. If this was a complex path parameter, you could instead follow the approach described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72815364/17865804), which would allow you to capture the whole URL path, including characters such as `/` and `%`, but still not text/values after `#`.

### Update

Since the "fragment" is only available/accessible on client side, you could use JavaScript to obtain the `hash` property of the `Location` interface, i.e., [`window.location.hash`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/hash). To do that, you could have a `/callback_init` endpoint that is initially called and used as the `redirect_uri` for the authorization server, and which will return the relevant JavaScript code to read the fragment and pass it in the query string of the URL to the final `/callback` endpoint. This can easily be done by replaing the `#` with `?` in the URL, as follows:

```py
@app.get('/callback_init', response_class=HTMLResponse)
async def callback_init(request: Request):
    html_content = """
    <html>
       <head>
          <script>
             var url = window.location.href;
             newUrl = url.replace('/callback_init', '/callback').replace("#", "?");
             window.location.replace(newUrl);
          </script>
       </head>
    </html>
    """
    return HTMLResponse(content=html_content, status_code=200)
```

**However**, the approach above would not respect the possibility of query parameters already present in the URL (even though this is not an issue in your case); hence, one could instead use the below.

The example below also takes into account that you had set a cookie, which you had to remove afterwards; hence, this is demonstrated below as well. Also, note that for replacing the URL in the browser's address bar (in other words, sending a request to the `/callback` endpoint), [`window.location.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/replace) is used, which, as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75188418/17865804), won't let the current page (before navigating to the next one) to be saved in session history, meaning that the user won't be able to use the back button in the browser to navigate back to it (if, for some reason, you had to allow the user going back, you could use [`window.location.href`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/href) or [`window.location.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/assign) instead).

If you would like hiding the path and/or query parameters from the URL, you can use an approach similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73088816/17865804) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70946019/17865804). However, this wouldn't mean that the URL, including such path/query parameters would not make it to the browsing history, etc., already. Hence, you should **be aware** that sending sensitive information in the query string is **not safe**—please refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73599289/17865804) for more details on that subject.

##### Working Example

To trigger the redirection, please go to your browser and call `http://localhost:8000/`.

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request, Response
from fastapi.responses import RedirectResponse, HTMLResponse
from typing import Optional


app = FastAPI()


@app.get("/")
async def main():
    redirect_url = 'http://localhost:8000/callback_init?msg=Hello#code=1111&state=2222'
    response = RedirectResponse(redirect_url)
    response.set_cookie(key='some-cookie', value='some-cookie-value', httponly=True)
    return response
    
    
@app.get('/callback_init', response_class=HTMLResponse)
async def callback_init(request: Request):
    html_content = """
    <html>
       <head>
          <script>
             var url = window.location.href;
             const fragment = window.location.hash;
             const searchParams = new URLSearchParams(fragment.substring(1));
             url = url.replace('/callback_init', '/callback').replace(fragment, "");
             const newUrl = new URL(url);            
             for (const [key, value] of searchParams) {
                newUrl.searchParams.append(key, value);
            }
             window.location.replace(newUrl);
          </script>
       </head>
    </html>
    """
    return HTMLResponse(content=html_content, status_code=200)


@app.get("/callback")
async def callback(
    request: Request,
    response: Response,
    code: Optional[str] = None,
    state: Optional[str] = None,
):
    print(request.url.query)
    print(request.cookies)
    response.delete_cookie("some-cookie")
    return {"code": code, "state": state}
```

Comment: I don't have control over the callback response from Azure AD, I am getting the # in the callback URL from Azure AD.

Comment: Have you tried setting the `response_mode` to `query` instead of `fragment`? Have a look at the [relevant documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow#request-an-authorization-code)

Comment: I am following this documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow#request-an-id-token-as-well-or-hybrid-flow and I don't see any way to get both id_token and code from Azure AD without fragment.

Comment: Yes, I checked that, but when I set response_mode to query don't return id_token.

Comment: As noted in the docs (see the link just posted by you): _"The use of `fragment` as a response mode causes issues for web apps that read the code from the redirect. Browsers don't pass the fragment to the web server. In these situations, apps should use the `form_post` response mode to ensure that all data is sent to the server."_

Comment: In the same docs page: _"We recommend apps use `form_post`, especially when using `http://localhost` as a redirect URI."_

Comment: Yes, I tried using form_post as well, but then I had to change my app.get to app.post for the redirect to receive the id_toke, code from Form Body, but then there was another issue with cookies. I am setting some cookie value in my first function where redirect is generated, and then in my redirect method, I am not able to retrieve that cookie.

Comment: The answer above has been updated.